# NullPointer Exception during testing of upsert method in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito, mono

I have a method which updates the data in MongoDB like this :

```
public Mono<SomeDTO> DoAction(SomeDTO someDTOObject) {
        return findUser(someDTOObject.getUsername())
                .flatMap(existingUser -> {
                    Update update = new Update();
                   
                    return mongoTemplate.upsert(
                            Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is(someDTOObject.getUsername())),
                            update,
                            SomeDTO.class,
                            COLLECTION_NAME)
                            .flatMap(updateResult -> {              /////// exception thrown from here
                                if(updateResult.wasAcknowledged())
                                    return Mono.just(existingUser);
                                else
                                    return Mono.error(new Exception("Unable to update customer"));
                            });                            

                }).switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer(() -> {
                            return Mono.error(new Exception("User Name doesn't exist."));
                        })
                );
    }
```

Test method for the above method is like this :

```
@Test
    public void DoAction_TestException() {
        SomeDTO someDTOObject = databaseUtil.SomeDTOMock;        

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("username").regex("^"+userId+"$","i"));
        doReturn(Mono.empty()).when(mongoTemplate).findOne(query,
                SomeDTO.class, "COLLECTION_NAME");
        
        UpdateResult acknowledged = UpdateResult.acknowledged(1, 1L, null);

        doReturn(Mono.just(acknowledged)).when(mongoTemplate).upsert(
                Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is(userId)),
                update,
                SomeDTO.class,
                "COLLECTION_NAME");
        
        SomeDTO someDTOObjectResult = mongoImpl.DoAction(someDTOObject).block();
        
        assertEquals(someDTOObject, someDTOObjectResult);
       
       
    }
```

When I run/debug this test method , a NullPOinterException is thrown at the line metnioned in the comments.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Many thanks.

Comment: Show UpdateResult class code

Comment: @bimjhi, It is a mongo client class : https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/result/UpdateResult.html

Comment: Provided info is not enough yet. We don't know your main method and the way you have initialized updateResult reference.

Comment: I have not initialized updateResult anywhere in the code other than what is shown here in the test method.

Comment: This code is part of API written in java. There is a controller method through which we receive someDTOObject as body. I send the same object to repository to update in the database.

Comment: As far as I can see from https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/java-setup-crud-operations/ updateResult is supposed to be a non-static variable which needs a prior initialization. try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(System.getProperty("mongodb.uri"))) { MongoDatabase sampleTrainingDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("sample_training");
            MongoCollection<Document> gradesCollection = sampleTrainingDB.getCollection("grades"); UpdateResult updateResult = gradesCollection.updateOne(eq("student_id", 10000), set("comment", "You should learn MongoDB!"));

Comment: Looks like your upsert mock doesn't work. Try to check it changing upsert args with `any()`

Comment: @Alex, you are my life savior. I have changed all arguments to any() and it worked. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close a question and according to comments. Your problem occurs cause of your mock `upsert` doesn't invoke. It maybe because of different expected arguments for mock and arguments you pass in method. You may try to change arguments to `any()` if it is not important for you to pass specific arguments